# About the method setDisplayZoomControls() in WebSetting

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a question that, in android 4.0. the method setDisplayZoomControls(boolean b) does work when b is true,  but when b is false, I need to reload webview to make it works.

Is there any problem with setDisplayZoomControls() method in Android 4.0?